# Browser Compatibility screwing with margins

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, browser, cross-browser, margin

I have an issue that has just recently come to my attention. We have a report that clients can view. Works perfectly fine in Firefox because that's what we use to test normally. Well we've had 2 isolated incidents of where a client loaded it in chrome or ie and the margins and spacing are completely messed up.

Here is a photo...chrome on left, firefox on right..it is suppose to look just like it does in firefox.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0h3Dv.jpg

i can look at 50 different reports by the same people and all are fine except for this 1...well now its 2 but i'm totally lost as to what caused this. Like the only thing i can thing of is it is in the data and for some reason something in the data is actually messing with the settings, but i havent seen anything that would cause it. is there any special characters that ie would recognize that firefox just skips over... also..if you need me to post code i can...but its long. I've set widths of table cells and of tale for these specific pages ignore the widths. All the reports work fine in chrome/firefox/ie except for these 2. Thanks for any help or advice.

EDIT:
i did limit it the the part that i think seems to cause the problem, at least the part that is messed up in the image i sent

this doesnt show any changes i have made..this is just what the original was, so even though for every cell i went in and set widths, as i said in OP, it didnt affect it so i went with original code

here is the reports.aspx.cs page

http://pastebin.com/vvbxASeq

here is the css page

http://pastebin.com/e0XMn4Lj

sorry for length - had to use pastebin links because it was too many characters for SO.

Edit 2: same id number for that report...so far..i have 2 id numbers that do this....but all the others seem to work fine..it makes me think its more of a data issue..but at same time..something in that data is causing explorer and chrome to freak out..i'm more of just trying to figure out why they are freaking out or why is firefox not freaking out..and it might help me find the thing causing the whole problem, because when i look at the data in the db ..it all looks fine and matches other reports that display correctly..but it might be something so small that i dont even realize it.

Comment: I see that you have blocked some of the data for obvious security reasons, but some code would be helpful otherwise someone could only guess whats there and not give you a reasonable or effective answer.

Comment: On the issue now it looks like a CSS problem (i guess). Try adding a `display:block; overflow:none;` to the parent element of your content.

Comment: ok..i will post the code..it is long though...i'll make an edit

Comment: ok..problem i believe is hyperlinks are crazy long in one section..and firefox handles wrapping them easily ..but ie and others dont..maybe..so...anyway to fix that..maybe in css file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turned out to be some data that was making it mess up..IE doesnt forcebreak a url..or long string of characters automatically..did a force break..and a few style adjustments..and got it to work.